# ruby on railsで同じページに複数のpost情報を作る

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby on railsで
同じhtmlファイルにひとつのactionしか呼び出されなくて困ってます。

```
# routes.rb
match 'users' => 'users#hoge',:via => :post 
match 'users' => 'users#foo', :via => :post

# users view
form_for @users, :url => {:action => 'hoge'} do |f|
  f.email
  f.hoge
 .
 .
 .      
  submit  
 end 

form_for @users, :url => {:action => 'foo'} do |f|
  f.email
  f.hoge
 .
 .
 .      
  submit  
end
```

こう指定してみましたが呼ばれませんでした。
これだとhoge actionしか呼ばれなかったです。
同じページにpostアクションを２つつけることはできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

### 期待通りの動作にならない理由

> http://railsguides.jp/routing.html
>
> Railsのルーティングは、ルーティングファイルの「上からの記載順に」マッチします。このため、たとえばresources :photosというルーティングがget 'photos/poll'よりも前の行にあれば、resources行のshowアクションがget行の記述よりも優先されますので、get行のルーティングは有効になりません。

`rake routes`などでルーティングを確認すると。２つの定義はどちらも
`POST   /users(.:format)`となっていて、衝突しているためです。

### 解決の一例

こういった記述が保守的な観点から好ましいかどうかは別として。

```
match 'users/hoge' => 'users#hoge',:via => :post
match 'users/foo'  => 'users#hoge',:via => :post
```

とすることで

```
users_hoge POST   /users/hoge(.:format)
users_foo  POST   /users/foo(.:format)
```

という結果が得られます。`match 'users/:action'`という方法もありますが
そちらの方法は、上で引用した railsguides.jp の内容を確認してください。

そして、form_forには

```
form_for @users, url: users_hoge_path
form_for @users, url: users_foo_path
```

とすれば良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

「Railsのレールに乗る」という観点から言うと、resourceルーティングを活用した方がベターかなと思います。

というわけでこんなふうにしてみるのはどうでしょうか？

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    post :hoge
    post :foo
  end
end

# rake routes
hoge_users POST /users/hoge(.:format) users#hoge
foo_users  POST /users/foo(.:format)  users#foo

# view
form_for @user, url: hoge_users do |f|
# ...
form_for @user, url: foo_users do |f|
```

ちなみに`@users`の中身は1件のUserだと思うので、単数形の`@user`の方が良いと思います。
複数形だと配列のように見えてしまうので。

Comment: Junichi ito 
Norikaz Ishii
ありがとうございます。解決出来ました。